# Why is the 'o' is true? Javascript(Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Help me please, I'm trying to make a rule for the little game and there is the problem. 
I'm creating winning combination and say if the cell && cell+1 && cell+2 == to 'X' then you win, but when between two "X"s presents "o" it also says that "X" wins. Why? Please see my code and the game example on link a the bottom.

```
this.rezult = function(){
  this.arr2.forEach(function(arr, i, innerArr){
    arr.forEach(function(val, j){
      var wincomb = innerArr[i][j] && innerArr[i][j+1] && innerArr[i][j+2];
      var wincomb2 = innerArr[i][j] && innerArr[i+1][j] && innerArr[i+2][j];
      var wincomb3 = innerArr[i][j] && innerArr[i+1][j+1] && innerArr[i+2][j+2];

      console.log(wincomb == "X" && innerArr[i][j] !== "o");
      // console.log(innerArr);
      // THE RULE

      if(wincomb == "X"){
        alert(' X wins!');
      }
    });        
  });
 };
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/12/)

Comment: What is the content of `innerArr`?

Comment: Is it `"o"` or is it `0` (zero)?

Comment: It's 2D empty array. And by clicking it's fills by the "X" or "o" randomly.

Comment: No, it's not a ZERO it's "o"

Comment: Then how can you make logical statements like `innerArr[i][j] && ...`? if it equals the string `"o"` it would evaluate to `true`

Comment: Can you explain why? Couse "X" == "o"  is false

Comment: Yes... so, I'm actually confused by what you are trying to do.. .are you evaluating for truthness when you do `innerArr[i][j] && innerArr[i][j+1]...`? What is the intent of `wincombN`?

Comment: This is should be the position of element in array:
var innerArray = [ [1,2,2], [4,5,6]];   So if the innerArray[0][1] && innerArray[0][2]  == 2   it's should say you win, as I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `&&` operator has interesting behavior with non-boolean values.
If the left-side of `&&` is "truthy", the result is the right-side.
If the left-side of `&&` is "falsey", the result is the left-side.

All non-empty strings are "truthy".

So, consider these examples:

```
("A" && "B" && "C") === "C"
("" && "B" && "C") === ""
(0 && "B" && "C") === 0
("X" && "X" && "O") === "O"
("O" && "O" && "X") === "X"
```

By the looks of it, you're trying to check if all 3 values are equal.  You shouldn't use `&&` for that, you should use === for that.

At the risk of doing your homework for you ;) here's a good way to do this:

```
function areTheSame(a,b,c) {
    return a === b && b === c;
}
var down = areTheSame(innerArr[i][j], innerArr[i][j+1], innerArr[i][j+2]);
var across = areTheSame(innerArr[i][j], innerArr[i+1][j], innerArr[i+2][j]);
var diagonal = areTheSame(innerArr[i][j], innerArr[i+1][j+1], innerArr[i+2][j+2]);

if (down || across || diagonal) {
    var winner = innerArr[i][j];
    alert( winner + " wins!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that.  Could you please show me little example how to implement this with function? This rule is in the function this.rezult = function(){  already

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me, I did rewrite the rule to:
(innerArr[i][j] === "X" && innerArr[i][j+1] === "X" && innerArr[i][j+2]) === "X"  and now it works :)   
But if as you said to do it with the function is better and more correct, please show me how, I would appreciate your help

Comment: At the risk of doing your homework for you ;) I went ahead and implemented the `areTheSame` solution.  See updated answer.  In JavaScript, functions can be declared almost anywhere.

Comment: No, it's ok, it is not my homework, I'm just learning Javascript and trying to understand how to do it correct and more professional. I've already done it in another way, but thank you very very much you variant would also be useful for my learning :)